# How to read .DAT file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have a .DAT file which if i open as text in Notepad gives me values like `#¨¤³¦+eäÌIóÆ‹,j°`.I got this file from a machine and there i got a documentation to open this file manually.As per that

```
1. Rename each file extensions of TAXA files from .DAT to .GZ
2. Uncompress (or unzip) all TAXAxxxx.GZ (you can use ZIP)
3. After the file extractions, rename each file with file extensions as TAXAxxxx.TXT
```

Here is the code that i tried..

```
        string str = "";
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(@"F:\TAXAZ.DAT"));
        foreach (char ch in br.ReadChars(5000))
        str += ch;
        br.Dispose();
```

This is happening manually as per the instructions mentioned above but when i am trying to do it programatically it is not happening.I tried zipping and unzipping concept but its in vain .Later i tried to read in binary and after that convert into string but that also of no use .
Please help me to read this file as text.
Thanks..

Comment: Please show us *exactly* what you have tried.

Comment: When you unzipped it, did you get a bunch of files that came out of that process? Are you trying to unzip from code or the explorer window?

Comment: @EBrown I updated my post with code that i tried ..please help me..

Comment: Step 2 tells you to decompress the files, your code does not attempt to do that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That is where i am lagging behind.can you tell me how to decompress the file

Comment: @RonBeyer I am trying to unzip it from the code.but i am not able to do it ..Please help me

Comment: @EBrown I tried the below code in the answer but it is also not giving me readable format of file..Please help

Answer (score 2):

Your instructions say you have to rename the .dat to a .gz, unzip it, and then read the file.
Your code is skipping the first 2 steps and just trying to read the file.  That's why it isn't working.

You can do this in C#, but you need to decompress it.  You can use [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this.

example C# code from that link:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace zip
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string directoryPath = @"c:\temp";
        public static void Main()
        {
            DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
            Compress(directorySelected);

            foreach (FileInfo fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
            {
                Decompress(fileToDecompress);
            }
        }

        public static void Compress(DirectoryInfo directorySelected)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in directorySelected.GetFiles())
            {
                using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
                {
                    if ((File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & 
                       FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".gz")
                    {
                        using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
                        {
                            using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, 
                               CompressionMode.Compress))
                            {
                                originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);

                            }
                        }
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(directoryPath + "\\" + fileToCompress.Name + ".gz");
                        Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                        fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), info.Length.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
        {
            using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
            {
                string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
                string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);

                using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
                {
                    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fileToDecompress.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code ..I tried to execute this code but as per my requirement i need to Compress and uncompress the `.DAT` file not the directory or folder .How to do it ..I tried to but its giving me error..Please help me ..

Comment: I copied the whole example from the site, but you just need the Decompress function here.  Pass in a FileInfo for your .dat file.  That should decompress it and write the file to disk.  You can change what you do with the decompressionStream if you don't want to write it to disk.

Comment: Okay.I manually changed the extension of the file to `.gz` and after that tried to decompress the same file using decompress function of the code shared by you but got following error ..`The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.' What is this and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Please help me sir ..i tried my best to get the solution but not able to get success ..Please

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
string filePath = @"C:/TAXAZ.dat";
    
string itemData;
    
FileStream f = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
 {
      itemData= sr.ReadToEnd();
 }
 Console.WriteLine(itemData);
```

you can used BinaryReader instead of StreamReader

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filePath , FileMode.Open)))
 {   
      itemData = reader.ReadString();
 }
```